# open html page on my hardrive - sinatra project

Tags: html, hyperlink, sinatra

In my erb file, this works as expected:

```
<INPUT  type="button" target="_blank" value="Preview" name="button0" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');" >
```

however I need to open an html page on my hardrive.  This works, if I put the file in my static directory:

```
<INPUT  type="button" target="_blank" value="Preview" name="button0" onclick="window.open('test.html');" >
```

I had made /static available with this code from the main.ru page:

```
set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'
```

but i need to open up an html page from a path that's like ../../../blah/blah/blah/test.html, and nothing seems to work.  Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to provide the whole path like

```
<INPUT  type="button" target="_blank" value="Preview" name="button0" onclick="window.open('YourDriveLetter://YourFolder/static/test.html');" >
```

for just a example....

```
<INPUT  type="button" target="_blank" value="Preview" name="button0" onclick="window.open('C:\mysite\static\blah\blah\blah\...\test.html');" >
```

and for include one...

```
set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'C:\mysite\static\'
```

hope it worked!

Good Luck!